# Split array of numbers to several parts with close values

Tags: arrays, collections

Example array:

```
[
    1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 30
]
```

I need it to split into three parts with close values

```
[1, 2, 3]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[20, 21, 22, 30]
```

The array can be different, but the logic is the same. Can any suggest some approach (mathematical model, theory, distribution or etc) to do it?
[image]

Comment: By "close" values you mean consecutive I'm guessing.  Do the numbers have to be in order within the array or could you have [1,9,2,3,8] and return [1,2,3] and [8,9]?

Comment: Nope, the array is always sorted by asc

Comment: Start with the first element, N, and see if the next element equals N+1. If it does, add it to the array.  If not, put that number in a new array and repeat.  (you can use a 2D array to build this up)

Answer (score 0):

The term "split array with close values" is ambiguous.

You can check whether the difference between two consecutive values is within a specific range. If the difference is in the specified range, then you can add the current value to the current sub list. Else you need to add to the next list:

```py
prev = 0
cnt = 1

for elm in A:
    if elm - prev not in range(0, 5):
        cnt += 1
    add_to_sub(cnt, elm)
    prev = elm
```

`cnt` variable is used to determine which sub list we should add the value. For the question, I set the range between 0-5. This means if the difference is greater than or equal to 5, than add the current value to the next sub-list.

Code:

```py
A = [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 30]

sub1 = []
sub2 = []
sub3 = []

prev = 0
cnt = 1


def add_to_sub(count, element):
    if count == 1:
        sub1.append(element)
    elif count == 2:
        sub2.append(element)
    else:
        sub3.append(element)


for elm in A:
    if elm - prev not in range(0, 5):
        cnt += 1
    add_to_sub(cnt, elm)
    prev = elm

print(sub1)
print(sub2)
print(sub3)
```

Result:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
[20, 21, 22, 30]
```

Answer (score 0):

With all the values in the source array already sorted, this makes it very easy.

In your example, I'll say there are 3 solutions.

```
solution 1: [1, 2, 3]
solution 2: [10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
solution 3: [20, 21, 22, 30]
```

Each solution is an array. We'll use another array to contain all these solutions.  Unless your source array is empty, you'll have at least 1 solution containing at least 1 value.

Take the first value from the source and begin creating solution 1. Now loop through the remaining values in the source. If the next value is consecutive to the most recent value added in the current solution, add it to that solution set. If not, begin creating a new solution.

```
source = [1, 2, 3, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 20, 21, 22, 30];
solutions = new Array(1);

index = 0;
solutions[index] = new Array();
solutions[index].push(source[0]);

j = 0;
for (i = 1; i < source.length; i++){

    if (solutions[index][j]+1 == source[i]){
        solutions[index].push(source[i]);
        j++
    }else{
        solutions.push(new Array());
        index++;
        solutions[index].push(source[i]);
        j = 0;
    }
}

console.log(solutions);
```